# entity framework 5, delete one to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework-5

The relationship of entity A,B is one-to-many, (A has many Bs, B must belong to A).

I disabled `lazy loading` and load A, B like this:

```cs
dbContext.As.Load();
//**particaly load B** 
dbContext.Bs.Where(predicateX).Load();
```

When I use

```cs
dbContext.As.Remove(someA)
```

To delete A, I encounter the following error message

`The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable`

Instead, if I use:

```cs
//remove all B in someA
foreach(B b in someA.Bs.ToList())
{
   dbContext.Bs.Remove(b);
}
dbContext.As.Remove(someA)
```

everything is ok.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**

---

i am using Database First and add foreign key constraint of B (on delete cascade) at the database side.

i think "the foreign key constraint" is just equal to the code "OnModelCreating". but the code "dbContext.As.Remove(someA)" doesn't work as expected.

things get worse when there is A-B-C cascade one to many relation.in order to delete someA,you need to do like this

```
foreach(B b in someA.Bs.ToList())
{
  foreach(C c in b.Cs.ToList())
  {
    dbContext.Cs.Remove(c);
  }
  dbContext.Bs.Remove(b);
}
dbContext.As.Remove(someA);
```

**Solved:**

---

i use database first(sqlite) and add foreign key constraint at database side.

use vs2012 to create edmx from sqlite database file,

vs2012 failed to set the "on delete cascade" property of the relationship.

after manual set the property,single call to "dbContext.As.Remove(someA)" work as expected!

Comment: what's wrong with my question?

Comment: There is no better ways for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, there is (currently) no batch support in Entity Framework, so you're stuck `foreach`-ing through multiple properties. You might want to look at the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) project, which adds various batch operations to tidy up code like this (as well as improving performance).

If you're sure you'll always want to delete the related B's when an A is deleted, then configure this relationship to use "on delete cascade" behaviour. What that means is that when a parent A is deleted, all of its child B's are automatically deleted as well. How to do that depends on how you've created the database. If you're using Code First, it'll be something like this:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.Bs)
                    .WithRequired(b => b.A)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer！but problem with "WithRequiredPrincipal(b => b.A)" , the lamda expression "b" is the type "ICollection<B>" not "B"?

Comment: Oops, my mistake - it's just `WithRequired` for one-to-many relationships (or rather, for looking back up from the child to parent). I've fixed my answer.

Comment: please see my new Edit.

Comment: You should be able to keep doing the same. `modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasMany(b => b.Cs).WithRequired(c => c.B).WillCascadeOnDelete();` etc.

Comment: this just work for Code First not for Database First.i think "foreign key constraint" at the database is just equal to the code "OnModelCreating".

Comment: Like I said, it depends on how you've created the database. If you're creating the database separately, then you'll need to set ON DELETE CASCADE on the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your patience！i find the cause of the problem!! i use  database first(sqlite) and add foreign key constraint at database side.use vs2012 to create edmx from sqlite database file,vs2012 failed to set the "on delete cascade" property of the relationship.after manual set the property,single call to "dbContext.As.Remove(someA)" work as expected!

Comment: Excellent. If this answer helped, please mark it as accepted so that future visitors can see.